# How to reduce time cost of initializing containers on Github Actions?

Tags: docker, github, containers, github-actions

Here is my action progress.

[image]

We can see the time of initializing containers is very long.

On circle CI, the time is about 30 seconds. However in github actions, it costs twice.

How to reduce the time cost? (i.e. local Docker image, caching image, …)

Comment: Are you using a very big base image? You could try switching it to a smaller one.

Comment: can you share your workflow file?